# Store Handle in custom data field?

Tags: haskell, handle

One more stupid question =) I have a custom data type with `Handle` field:

```
import System.IO

data CustomType = CustomType {
    file::Handle
}
```

How can I set a `file` field? I'm trying to use this obvious code:

```
let someFile = openFile fileName AppendMode
let object = CustomType {
    file=someFile
}
```

but `openFile` has a type `openFile :: FilePath -> IOMode -> IO Handle`, so I've got an error

```
Couldn't match expected type `Handle' with actual type `IO Handle'
```

So how can I store `Handle` object in this field?

**UPD**

I'm trying also this

```
data CustomType = CustomType {
    file::IO Handle
}
```

but this results to an error, when I'm using the `hPutStrLn` function

```
let object = CustomType {
    file=someFile
}
hPutStrLn (file object)
```

Error message is:

```
 Couldn't match expected type `Handle' with actual type `IO Handle'
    In the return type of a call of `file'
    In the first argument of `TO.hPutStrLn', namely `(file object)'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      TO.hPutStrLn (file object) text
```

Comment: What about using the `IO Handle` type in the `file` record?

Comment: It's ok, but then I don't know how to use ``hPutStrLn`` (I'm trying ``hPutStrLn (file object)`` where object is ``CustomType``)

Comment: You'll have to use the `IO monad`:  `file object >>= \h -> hputStrLn h "someline"`. Does that work for you? I could give a longer explanation as an answer below.

Comment: @DannyNavarro Sorry for the too late reply. Yes, it work for me. But what is the more correct choice - store ``IO Handle`` or ``Handle`` record? Also, I suppose, I must learn more about the ``IO`` monad - but I would be glad to see you answer with a longer explanation =)

Comment: Using `IO Handle` in your type would be a quick and dirty solution, but in general, in Haskell, it's usually better to make `IO` code as thin as possible. This way you can take advantage of Haskell's purity. So using just `Handle` in your type, as shown in the answers below, it's, I think, better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what you want. If you don't understand type errors involving `IO` type mismatches, you should probably read an introduction to IO in Haskell first. Anyway, this is code that works:

```
import System.IO

data CustomType = CustomType {
    file :: Handle
  }

fileName :: FilePath
fileName = "foo"

process :: IO ()
process = do
  someFile <- openFile fileName AppendMode
  let object = CustomType { file = someFile }
  hPutStrLn (file object) "abc"
  hClose (file object)
```

If you want to type the commands in GHCi instead, you can enter every line of the `do`-block in the `process` action individually, like this:

```
GHCi> someFile <- openFile fileName AppendMode
GHCi> let object = CustomType { file = someFile }
GHCi> hPutStrLn (file object) "abc"
GHCi> hClose (file object)
```

Answer (score 2):

So you have created your type like this:

```
data CustomType = CustomType {
    file::Handle
}
```

Now try this in ghci:

```
ghci> let a = openFile "someFile.txt" AppendMode
ghci> :t a
a :: IO Handle
```

So `Handle` is wrapped with `IO` type. You can use the Monad bind operator
to extract the `Handle` out of it.

```
ghci> let b = a >>= \handle -> return $ CustomType handle
```

The `return` function will wrap the `CustomType` again in the `IO` monad. You can verify this again in the ghci:

```
ghci> :t b
b :: IO CustomType
```

The type of `bind` or `>>=` is like this:

```
ghic> :t (>>=)
(>>=) :: Monad m => m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

Try to replace `m` with `IO` and you get:

```
(>>=) :: IO a -> (a -> IO b) -> IO b
```

And that's why you have to use `return` function with the `bind` operator, so that it will typecheck.

Answer (score 1):

So your confusion seems to be with how to use values inside a IO monad. The thing about the IO monad is that its infectious, so whenever you want to do something with a IO value you will get a IO result. This might sound like a pain in the ass, but its actually pretty nice in reality as it keeps the parts of your program pure and gives you complete control over when actions are performed. Instead of trying to get out of the IO monad you have to learn to embrace the haskell way of applying functions to monadic values. Every monad is a functor so you can apply a pure function to a monadic value with fmap. The extra power a monad gives is that it allows you to join contexts together. So if you have a `IO a` and a `IO b` you can join the IO's together to get `IO (a, b)`. We can use this knowledge to solve your problem:

openFile has the signature:

```
openFile :: FilePath -> IOMode -> IO Handle
```

As mentioned above there is no way* to remove the IO from Handle, so the only thing you can do is to put your type inside the IO monad too. You can for example make this function that uses fmap to apply your object to the `IO Handle`:

```
createMyObject :: FilePath -> IO CustomType
createMyObject fp = CustomType `fmap` openFile fp AppendMode
```

Now you have your object but its in a IO monad so how do you use it? The outermost layer of your application is always in the IO monad. So your main function should have a signature like `IO ()`. Inside the main function you can use other IO values like they are pure by using do notation. The `(<-)` keyword is kind of like join we talked about above. It draws the value from another IO into the current IO:

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    myObjectPure <- createMyObject "someFilePath.txt"

    let myHandle :: Handle -- No IO!
        myHandle = file myObjectPure

    -- Now you can use the functions that takes a pure handle:
    hPutStrLn myHandler "Yay"
```

By the way you probably shouldn't use a Handle directly this way because it will be really easy for you to forget to close it. Its better to use something like `withFile` which will close the handle for you when its done.

**Actually there is a way, but you don't need to know about it yet because its very unlikely that you are solving a problem that actually needs it, and its too easy to abuse for someone new.*